# How to set a dynamic loop

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am new to matlab and I don't know how to solve this problem.I have an array of 85 doubles and I want to browse the array 9 by 9 (ie: for `i=1:9`).I want to plot then the results in a figure (3*3).
To explain the code, I am trying browse a DATA contained in the arrays Start and End and then plot a power spectrum each time so the output be 9 curves (or I could some left overs).

```
figure   
for j=1:9  
    BinData=ExtractContinuousData([],Info,[7],Start(j),End(j),[]);
    [S1,t,f]=mtspecgramc(BinData); 
    subplot(3,3,j)
    plot_matrix (S1,t,f);    
end

%Start and End are the arrays that contains the 85 doubles each
```

But the problem is I just can plot the first 9 elements.
If I want to browse for example the 10th element (`j=10`), the command `plot(3,3,j)` wouldn(t work because the maximal value that `j` can take in this case is 9.

Comment: What is the output of `mtspecgramc`? Are you sure you can directly use the three outputs in the `plot` function?

Comment: yes  I am sorry ,It's plot_matrix (3,3,j).

Comment: Which line is throwing the error in your code?

Comment: well,when I want to browse the next 9 elements (for j=10:18),I have this error:Error using subplot 
Index exceeds number of subplots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the third input of the `subplot` function is not allowed to exceed the product of the first two inputs. So in your case you want to generate a 3x3 grid of plots. What you could do is the following:

```
subplot(3,3,mod(j-1,9)+1)
```

This is calculating the modulo operation (the remainder of the division by 9) thus will never exceed 9.

Comment: Glad I could help! I just changed it to `mod(j+1,10)` because I believe this should give you the expected resulted (always iterating from 1 to 9).

Comment: No,I have this error:                                                                                                              Error using subplot 
Illegal plot number.

Comment: For which index number is that happening? `mod(j+1,10)` is not able to exceed 9, so you that shouldn't be the root of the error.

Comment: You could also try `subplot(3,3,mod(j-1,9)+1)`. Matlab is a little annoying with its 1-indexing ;-)